# Performance profiling application with non-pattern async calls:

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, asynchronous, profiling

I'm working on an existing large enterprise application. This application has a small asynchronous method framework built in to it's ViewModel base class. These async methods are similar to APM *and* the event-based asynchronous pattern. There are little bits from both established patterns that were borrowed.

I've been assigned to profile the performance of a particularly slow view in the application. I have been given a license to Redgate ANTS Performance Profiler for the job.

As far as I believe I have read today, ANTS is normally capable of linking async/await calls to the actual work done. However, since this application I am working on does not follow the async/await pattern, I believe I am missing out on this automatic linkage of Async calls to their execution to their completion handlers.

The actual work being performed is done by a service that is central to the application, so there are *hundreds* of things that are causing this service to perform work, constantly.

Because of this issue, what ANTS is showing me is the worker method being extremely slow, but it is giving me zero feedback on what inside the view is actually causing this slow work to be done.

I spoke to a coworker about this problem, and he told me this is why he doesn't bother with performance profilers. He told me that what he would do is put time stamped logging calls all over the view and then write a quick and dirty tool to filter the data into something consumable by a human. But this is pretty much exactly what the profiler should be doing for me.

We talked about this for a while and concluded that for a tool to be effective with Async calls, it would either have to support a specific standard, or it would have to support something *in* the actual code, perhaps such as an  attribute, that allows you to mark the async call and the completion handler.

Do you agree with what I've said here? If so, are there any such performance profilers for .NET that have custom attributes to annotate your problematic code with for profiling? If not, could you please enlighten me as to how I can interpret this data to determine the actual cause of the issue?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Did you ever find a good solution for profiling async code? I have a large async code base (using async/await) and all the profilers I tried (including ANTS which is supposed to support async) have been unable to give me meaningful results.

Comment: In another project where we were using async/await chaining extensively, the solution we ended up going with was to remove the async/await chaining from nearly the entire application, using it only in the client WPF viewmodels where it is really necessary. Everything else is now synchronous chains. I am completely unhappy with the solution, and it was a lot of work removing async/await. But it does work, and I can profile like a champ now.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Unfortunately, making the code synchronous is not an option (and it's not even desirable - on the whole, I'm very happy with the async implementation). Async code is virtually everywhere in the application, and anyway we can't really avoid it because we're using HttpClient, which only exposes an async API.

Comment: I feel basically the same way about this, but not being able to profile was even more of not an option for us. You could use .Result/.Wait() on the tasks to use HttpClient synchronously. We are doing this in our app now.